# Powershell split variable without new line or spaces

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to split the filename without extention and assign it to a new variable. But .split('') function adds new whitespace or tab. Any suggestion to fix this?

```
$dmpfile = "test.dmp"
$filename = $dmpfile.split('.dmp')
echo $filename
test

ls $filename*.log
no output.............
echo $filename*.log
test     *.log
```

Comment: Corrected typo $filename = $string.split('.dmp') to $filename = $dmpfile.split('.dmp')

Comment: `[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($dmpfile)`

Comment: That worked. split and trim both removes characters in the filename instead of extension. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the *split* function creates an object with all strings that appear between the split character. You have to access a single item of the property by using `$variable[x]`, where x would be the position of the item you want. In your case you would have to call `$filename[0]`. (First item is not 1, it starts with 0)

Second, I cannot realy explain why, but if you use the string method split like you did, every single character will be handled as possible delimiter. This is why `'pmdasdfgpmd.dmp'.split(".dmp")` will return *asdfg* - same as if you would use *trim*. But if you use the function like this:

```
'pmdasdfgpmd.dmp' -split".dmp"
```

it will return the filename without extension: *pmdasdfgpmd*

Third, if you want to remove a part of a string, you can also use the *replace* method and replace the string by nothing:

either

```
'test.dmp'.replace(".dmp","")
```

or

```
'test.dmp' -replace ".dmp"
```

But this is just about some basic string replacement in powershell - the easiest way the get the filename without extension is either the way @PetSerAl proposed:

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($dmpfile)
```

or you call the `Get-Item` PSFunction and use the `BaseName`-Property:

```
(Get-Item $dmpfile).BaseName
```

In both cases, the variable $dmpfile must hold the full path to the file, not only the file name.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Trim() instead of Split(). `$filename = $dmpfile.Trim(".dmp")`

Comment: Note that `'pmdasdfgpmd.dmp'.Trim(".dmp")` will return `asdfg`.